# AttributeError: 'TestTomsLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium

**conftest.py file**

```
    import pytest
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
    
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def setup(request):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get("https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/Login")
        driver.maximize_window()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        request.cls.driver = driver
        request.cls.driver = wait
        yield
        driver.close()
```

**loginpage.py file**

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    
    class TomsLogin:
        def __init__(self, driver, wait):
            self.driver = driver
            self.wait = wait
    
        def toms_login(self, usern, pwd):
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "Username").send_keys(usern)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "Password").send_keys(pwd)
```

**test_toms_login.py file** -- **Getting error while calling this file**

```
    import pytest
    from base.loginpage import TomsLogin
    
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
    class TestTomsLogin():
        def test_login(self):
            self.tl = TomsLogin(self.driver, self.wait)
            self.tl.toms_login("User1", "pwd1")
    
    ttl = TestTomsLogin()
    ttl.test_login()
```

**Error Details:**

```
collecting ... 
test_toms_login.py:None (test_toms_login.py)
test_toms_login.py:11: in <module>
    ttl.test_login()
test_toms_login.py:7: in test_login
    self.tl = TomsLogin(self.driver, self.wait)
E   AttributeError: 'TestTomsLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Comment: You declared `driver` locally in `setup`. You are also opening and closing it as part of the `setup` method. Making it a class attribute would resolve your main issue.         `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`. But since you are closing it early, you will probably end up calling something and get another error. Close it in `tearDown` instead

Comment: request.cls.driver = driver 
I have used request here to available over the class. So it should be available right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ttl = TestTomsLogin()
ttl.test_login()
```

The Issue got resolved by removing the above two lines. It should not be used when using pytest methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of you code to something like this:
And make sure driver is actually installing (you can use hard coded path once to see the problem)

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def driver(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/Login")
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request, driver):
    # put your wait here too
    request.cls.driver = driver
```